# h5read function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, hdf5

I'd like to read only part of the dataset of HDF5 file using h5read function in Matlab . Particularly in 1 of the dimensions I want to read only every 4th value.

I can read the whole dataset as:

```
tempp = hdf5read(nameCur,namedataset);
```

its size: 160x100x200x10.

Next, when I want to read the whole dataset using "start" and "count" attributes, it works fine:

```
tempp = h5read(nameCur,namedataset,[1 1 1 1],[160 100 200 10]);
```

Then I want to read all dataset using "stride" attribute too:

```
    tempp = h5read(nameCur,namedataset,[1 1 1 1],[160 100 200 10],[1 1 1 1]);
```

works nice!

But when I want finally to read every 4th value from second dimension

```
    tempp = h5read(nameCur,namedataset,[1 1 1 1],[160 100 200 10],[1 4 1 1]);
```

it gives me error:

```
Error using h5readc
The index arguments exceed the size of the dataset.
```

I don't understand what is the reason for that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by what you said about the arguments to h5read, you'll need to adjust the values in `count` to reflect the new stride.

Now you don't want to read 100 elements in the 2nd dimensions, since you would end up reading up to element 400, which does not exist.

Given this, you may want to try:

```
tempp = h5read(nameCur,namedataset,[1 1 1 1],[160 25 200 10],[1 4 1 1]);
```